# How do you make a css clip-path polygon transition smooth?

Tags: css, clip-path

I have a triangle that I want to morph smoothly into a different shape.

I am using a simply clip-path to do this.  I start with the clip path on an element and toggle a class that changes the clip path.  This is all pretty straight forward.

The clip path changes but the change is harsh.  I want a smooth transition. Any ideas?

```js
   $('button').click(function(){
  $('.shape').toggleClass('medium');
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

  .shape{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    background: black;
    position: initial;
    transition: clip-path 2s ease-in-out;
}

.shape.medium{
            clip-path: polygon(50% 1%, 63% 20%, 86% 15%, 81% 38%, 100% 50%, 81% 63%, 86% 86%, 63% 81%, 50% 100%, 37% 81%, 14% 86%, 19% 63%, 0% 50%, 19% 38%, 14% 15%, 37% 20%);
            transition: clip-path 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="button">
     <button>testing</button
  </div>
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My understanding is that you need the same number of points in each clip path for this to work.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/animating-with-clip-path/

Comment: thats @Paulie_D I have read that...  I was worried about that.

Comment: You can draw the triangle with as many points as the second shape has - placing them on one or other edge of the triangle. But you need to decide where they are to go initially as that will influence what the animation looks like. Have you decided how you want the animation to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a smooth transition the shapes have to have the same number of points.

We can give the triangle 16 points to correspond to the 16 points in the second shape.

Overlaying the two shapes we get this:

[image]

There are many ways of mapping the points onto the sides of the triangle of course, and you will have to decide what you want the transition to look like and work out (bit of trigonometry will be required!) what points on the lines AB, BC, CA you want the points 1,2, 3....to correspond to.

This snippet takes the lazy way out and maps points 1-4 to the top of the triangle, points 5-7 to the bottom right, 8-10 to the center bottom and the other points correspondingly up the left side.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.shape').toggleClass('medium');
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.shape {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0);
  background: black;
  position: initial;
  transition: clip-path 2s ease-in-out;
}

.shape.medium {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 1%, 63% 20%, 86% 15%, 81% 38%, 100% 50%, 81% 63%, 86% 86%, 63% 81%, 50% 100%, 37% 81%, 14% 86%, 19% 63%, 0% 50%, 19% 38%, 14% 15%, 37% 20%);
  transition: clip-path 2s ease-in-out;
}

</style><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="wrapper"><div id="button"><button>testing</button
```

```html
</div>
<div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```